# Implementing Lock, Unlock -Reentranlock

Tags: java

I got stuck trying to implement Lock Unlock synchronization. The below code has two threads trying to access one field at the same time, and this code I can implement synchronized keyword to make it synch, but I want to implement specifically Lock - unlock belonging to ReentrantLock class.

The first thread is 10000 and the second 10000. Once synchronized the output has to be 20000.

To implement Lock- Unlock I tried  the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class App 
{
    int count = 0;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        App a = new App();
        a.doWork();
    }

    public Lock sync = new ReentrantLock();
    public void synchronize()   //Here i created a method to try to make work the access one by one                         
    {
        sync.lock();
        try
        {
            count++;
        }
        finally
        {
            sync.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void doWork()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                        {
                            synchronize();
                        }

                    }

                });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                   public void run()
                   {
                       for (int i =0; i <10000; i++)
                           {
                           synchronize();
                           }
                   }
                });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("count is " + count);
    }
}
```

How do I implement specifically Lock - unlock from ReentrantLock class, no others methods.

Comment: What was unsuccessful about the code? You realize that you can't print out the count right after you've started the threads. The threads may not have had a chance to finish yet (you can use `t1.join(); t2.join();` to wait for the threads to finish).